# Is logic within a factory method acceptable?

Tags: php, drupal

Im in the process of creating a factory method which will be used to create a collection of Drupal Module's (objects).

In the creation of this collection through the factory method i want to ensure we're only adding modules to the collection that implement a specific hook. (In non Drupal terms this basically means a module [object] is of a certain type).

All of this filter logic is carried out in the factory method (which includes dependency injection principles) to return a collection of modules that implement the required hook.

I guess my question is.. is this an acceptable approach to take? Is it good practice to include this level of logic within a factory method etc etc.

The method in question: createFromModuleKeysImplementingHook

```
<?php

/**
 * Class ModuleCollectionFactory.
 *
 * Contains static factory methods that can be implemented to create
 * ModuleCollection objects.
 *
 * @package RuralStack\Common\Module
 */
final class ModuleCollectionFactory {

    /**
     * Create a ModuleCollection object from an array of Module keys.
     *
     * The following creation method will (for each passed Module key) create
     * a Module object which then added into the returned ModuleCollection
     * object.
     *
     * @param array $moduleKeys
     *     An array of Module keys to create the ModuleCollection object from.
     *
     * @return ModuleCollection The populate ModuleCollection object.
     */
    public static function createFromModuleKeys(array $moduleKeys){
        $moduleCollection = new ModuleCollection();
        foreach($moduleKeys as $moduleKey){
            $moduleCollection->add(Module::create($moduleKey));
        }
        return $moduleCollection;
    }


    /**
     * This is the method in question that implements the logic
     *
     * Is this good or bad practice?
     *
     * Is there a better way of doing this?
     *
     * @param array $moduleKeys
     * @param $hookName
     * @param HookInformationInterface $hookInformation
     *
     * @return ModuleCollection
     */
    public static function createFromModuleKeysImplementingHook(array $moduleKeys, $hookName, HookInformationInterface $hookInformation){

        /**
         * $moduleKeys = array('my_module', 'test_module', 'hook_module');
         *
         * $hookName = 'some_hook';
         *
         * $modulesInvokingHook = array('tm_dule, 'hook_module', 'my_module');
         *
         * array_intersect = array('hook_module', 'my_module');
         * ^^^Create the Module collection object from these
         */

        /**
         * Get all of the module keys that implement the hook (function) passed
         * to the factory method. Returns an array of module keys that matches
         * the format of the passed $moduleKeys argument.
         */
         $modulesInvokingHook = $hookInformation->getHookImplementations($hookName);

         $moduleCollection = new ModuleCollection();
         foreach(array_intersect($moduleKeys, $modulesInvokingHook) as $moduleKey){
            $moduleCollection->add(Module::create($moduleKey));
         }
         return $moduleCollection;
     }

}
```

Comment: I would say no. But you could had an optional check function as parameter which could be defined to validate only module using that hook.

Comment: Thanks for the response Kulvar, could you explain further please as i dont fully understand what you mean.

Comment: You can do `$moduleKeys = array_filter($moduleKeys, $filteringFunction);` before calling the method, or you can add a `callable $filteringFunction` as parameter and you ignore the module created in the `foreach(){}` that are not validated by the filtering function.